# Configuration of log4j2 Thread Context

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, log4j2

In my spring boot application I'm using log4j2. It's a typical web application. I have many connection and I want to separate logs for each connection.

I want to use [Thread Context](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test() throws InterruptedException
{
    try (final CloseableThreadContext.Instance ctc = CloseableThreadContext.push(UUID.randomUUID().toString()))
    {

        logger.info("start");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("end.");
    }
    return "response";
}
```

I'm testing in two terminals:`curl localhost:8000/test`. But I have the result:

```
14:09:27.895 [qtp401792389-21] INFO  Controllers.ContentController - start
14:09:28.062 [qtp401792389-19] INFO  Controllers.ContentController - start
14:09:28.896 [qtp401792389-21] INFO  Controllers.ContentController - end.
14:09:29.062 [qtp401792389-19] INFO  Controllers.ContentController - end.
```

It's mix of sessions, i want this:

```
14:09:27.895 [qtp401792389-21] INFO  Controllers.ContentController - start
14:09:28.896 [qtp401792389-21] INFO  Controllers.ContentController - end.
14:09:28.062 [qtp401792389-19] INFO  Controllers.ContentController - start
14:09:29.062 [qtp401792389-19] INFO  Controllers.ContentController - end.
```

So, is there any special configuration for this?

Answer (score 1):

The Log4j2 [FAQ has an example](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files) of how you can use the [RoutingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) to route logs to different files based on the ThreadContext key.

This uses the ThreadContext map, not the stack (so you'd need to use the `put` method instead of `push`).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but it is better if you use the MDC implementation for this with `ThreadContext.put(key, value)`. It is important to use the correct configuration like `{%20X}.`